# RandomVariate of a custom distribution gives only negative points

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I don't understand why the following code

```
dis = ProbabilityDistribution[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, -5, 5}];
data = RandomVariate[dis, 10^4];;
Show[
 Histogram[data, 20, "ProbabilityDensity"],
 Plot[PDF[dis, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 1}}]
```

Produces only negative data points?
At the same time for the `dis = NormalDistribution` it works fine.

[image: distribution picture]

Comment: It would probably be more useful if you self-answer. The question's code is simple, and I bet many people would have this problem too. Self-answering is a practice that is encouraged on this site.

Answer (score 10):

I understood it. The argument of the `ProbabilityDistribution` should be properly normalized. It would be actually useful if mathematica produced some kind of error message in this example. So the correct code should be:

```
norm = NIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, -5, 5}];
dis = ProbabilityDistribution[(1/(x^2 + 1))/norm, {x, -5, 5}];
data = RandomVariate[dis, 10^4];
Show[
 Histogram[data, 20, "ProbabilityDensity"],
 Plot[PDF[dis, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 0.4}}]
Export["c:/d/dist.png", %];
```

[image: corrected picture]

Comment: Note that in 10.2 and later you can do `ProbabilityDistribution[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, -5, 5},  Method -> "Normalize"]` and _Mathematica_ will take care of the normalization for you.